# Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs

Error is

Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationBar } from './components/header/Navbar';
import {Outlet} from "react-router-dom"


export default function App(){
  const [account, setAccount] = React.useState<string>('')
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavigationBar />
        <Outlet context={[account, setAccount]}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting error on the line `const {account, setAccount} = useOutletContext();`
Below is the snippet of code where account and setAccount is needed.

```
import { useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";
const NavigationBar:React.FC = () => {
    const [account, setAccount] = useOutletContext();
    // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `useOutletContext` as an object, but it is an array. So the `{}` should be a `[]` in this case.

Change it to

```
const [account, setAccount] = useOutletContext();
```

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext

---

Now that you're getting the Symbol.iterator error: you are supposed to set the context on a parent route and consume the context on an inner route. In your current code you are setting and consuming it on the same level.

See this codesandbox for a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/useoutletcontext-eg1fxb

Below is the code from the sandbox for complete reference

```
import React from "react";
import { Outlet, Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [account, setAccount] = React.useState("ACCOUNT-NAME");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Outer route</h1>
      <Outlet context={[account, setAccount]} />
    </div>
  );
};

const DashboardInner = () => {
  const [account, setAccount] = useOutletContext();
  return <div>Account: {account}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<DashboardInner />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested. got another error Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: Is that on a different line? Sounds like a different problem

Comment: on the same line

Comment: Updatet the answer

Comment: thanks! issue solved

Comment: I had to add **any** `const [account, setAccount]:any = useOutletContext();`